# Using Angular Material, is it possible to align one button to the left and another to the right, in the same row?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

According to [Angular Material's documentation on alignment](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment):

> The layout-align attribute takes two words. The first word says how
>   the children will be aligned in the layout's direction, and the second
>   word says how the children will be aligned perpendicular to the
>   layout's direction.

I used this to create the button section that you can see on the picture below:

[image]

With the following code:

```
<section layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="end center" layout-wrap>
  <md-button class="md-primary">Submit</md-button>
  <md-button class="md-warn">Cancel</md-button>
  <md-button class="md-warn">Delete Boundary Partner Type</md-button>
</section>
```

However, I wanted the `Submit` button to be left-aligned, and all the others right-aligned. Is there a correct way of doing this with Angular Material or will I just have to create my own styles?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do so with the help of a `div` and `layout-align` , here is the code:

```
<section layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="end center" layout-wrap>
  <div layout="row" layout-align="start center" flex>
    <md-button class="md-primary">Submit</md-button>
    <span flex></span>
  </div>
  <md-button class="md-warn">Cancel</md-button>
  <md-button class="md-warn">Delete Boundary Partner Type</md-button>
</section>
```

And a working [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/xZiHtOgXN871xu3X2inO?p=preview).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working if its wrapped inside a md-toolbar.

Comment: The buttons in your plunker are below eachother. The questions asks "one left and one right". I don't see how this helps.

Comment: I thought so too, but if you go to full screen preview, it is correct. It is because "layout-sm" is set to "column", but "layout" is set to "row". Basically, if the screen isnt big enough, it'll display as column, otherwise - row.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use

```
layout-align="space-between center"
```

See this exemple : https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/panel
(Last exemple)

Comment: works only for angularjs (v1) material, Not for Angular (v2+)

Answer (score 2):

`"space-between center"` works with Angular V5 and angular/flex-layout. 
You will have to use it as: `fxLayoutAlign = "space-between center"`.

Comment: I think this is best answer currently. It works and it is short.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for [Toolbar](https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/overview) shows a simple solution:

```html
<mat-toolbar>
  <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>     <-- left
  <span class="example-spacer"></                  <-- space in the middle
  <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon></button> <-- right
  <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>share</mat-icon></button>    <-- right
</mat-toolbar>
```

This puts the "hamburger menu" icon on the left and the heart ("favorite") and share icons on the right. The key is this little beauty:

```html
 <span class="example-spacer"></span>
```

with this CSS:

```css
.example-spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

The first parameter is a maximum amount of space, the second is the minimum, and the third is the ideal. `auto` means "fill up the space".

`flex: 0 1 auto` and `flex: none` make zero space, i.e., the heart and share icons go right.

You can even put one icon on the left, one in the middle, and one on the right:

```html
<mat-toolbar>
  <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>     <-- left
  <span class="example-spacer"></span>                           <-- space
  <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon></button> <-- middle
  <span class="example-spacer"></span>                          <-- space
  <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>share</mat-icon></button>    <-- right
</mat-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works with the most recent Angular.

If you want to align more than one button to left or right, you can simply group buttons with div.

For example, when you place Prev and Next button to left and close button to right,

```
<section fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
   <div>
      <button mat-button>Prev</button>
      <button mat-button>Nex</button>
    </div>
    <button mat-button cdkFocusInitial mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
</section>
```